# app.get req.body undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, mean

I'm a MEAN stack newb experiencing problems with routes, and presumably, parsing: The following code gets me a req.body: undefined.:

Server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/roomem');

var Roomie = require('./public/models/roomie.server.model');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var roomieRoutes = require('./public/routes/roomie.server.routes');

roomieRoutes(app);

module.exports = app;
app.listen('3000');
```

Controller.js:

```
roomem.controller('roomieCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$log', function($scope, $http, $location, $log)
    {
        $scope.login = function()
        {
            console.log($scope.person.meta);  // This outputs the object correctly
            $http.get('/roomielogin',$scope.person.meta).success(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);  // This returns null
            });
        }

    }]);
```

roomie.server.route.js:

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
    app.get('/roomielogin', function(req,res)
    {
        console.log(req.body);     // displays undefined
        console.log(req.headers);  // shows that the document can be json
        var name = req.body.username;
        var query  = Roomie.where({ 'meta.username': name });
        query.findOne(function(err, doc) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          console.log(doc);
          res.json(doc);
        });
    });
}
```

I have tried just about everything and read every post out there about this. Most of the time, people are just placing their app.use(bodyParser.json()); line too late in their script, but mine seems to be at the right place. All the other queries are working right. This is the only problematic one. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of doing `GET` if you are sending data in body you need to do
>   a `POST` request.

Change -

`$http.get('/roomielogin',$scope.person.meta)`

To

`$http.post('/roomielogin',$scope.person.meta)`

**&**

`app.get('/roomielogin', function(req,res)`

To

`app.post('/roomielogin', function(req,res)`

Comment: Ha! That worked! So why does a GET not work in this situation? Thanks btw!

Comment: Well, kinda worked. The controller successfully passes the data to the route. Problem now is that the route still returns a null response back to the calling controller. So half of the problem is solved!

Comment: @Nick thats a different question

Comment: What is coming in console.log(doc);

Comment: Instead the the JSON object that usually comes out, I get [Object object], which can't be unwrapped apparently since any attempt at referring to inner content gives me null. As a temporary workaround, I have set the controller to return a single string as opposed to an object, and I use that string to get the rest of what I need. I would prefer a regular object, of course.